# GWT RequestFactory and Spring-managed transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, gwt, transactions, requestfactory

I'm working on a GWT 2.5.1 + Spring 3.2 + Hibernate 4 project.
The Spring-Hibernate application is already working and has the usual Service/Dao layers. Transactions are handled by Spring through @Transactional annotations on service methods.

I'm trying to add the GWT layer on top of it using GWT RequestFactory.
In particular, I don't understand how RequestFactory and Spring-managed transactions should work together.

It seems like RequestFactory performs a lot of queries (see find/getId methods of Locator class) before and after actually calling the requested service method.
BTW: Should Locator rely on a Spring service bean to perform those queries? I guess so.

This means RequestFactory do things in different transactions, which is bad. 
I want the whole request to happen in the same transaction to take advantage of Hibernate cache (well, this is just the main reason).

I think @Transactional annotations should somehow be moved up to the GWT server layer, but they must be on a Spring bean in order to work, so...

What's the best way to integrate GWT RequestFactory and Spring-managed transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thomas is right. You need to use the Open Session in View pattern. Regarding `Spring` integration:

Just add this to your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Annotate your Service classes or methods with `@Transactional`.

Comment: And you need to use a `ServiceLocator` that loads services from Spring.

Comment: Thanks, this works correctly.

As for RequestFactory-Spring integration...
I've found a couple of working solutions:
1) http://jsinghfoss.tumblr.com/post/18216239637/gwt-2-2-0-requestfactory-spring-3-0-x-integration
2) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/IQInsMnPtT0/PNU41isLLnUJ (second post)

I'm still not sure which is better.
The second one is simpler but you need to get the ApplicationContext every time.

Comment: In any case, the basic idea is the following:
1) A custom ServiceLayerDecorator is supplied to GWT's RequestFactoryServlet constructor.  
2) The decorator is responsible for retrieving EntityLocators (Locator interface) and ServiceLocators, which are Spring-managed beans.  
3) You need only 1 ServiceLocator. Responsible for retrieving any Spring service bean.  
4) You need at least 1 EntityLocator, depending on how domain entities are implemented.  
5) EntityLocatord directly use the JPA EntityManager (or Hiberante SessionFactory)  

...add the filter above and it all falls into place. :)

Comment: I just finished a adapted version of the DynatableRequestFactory that uses Spring and Hibernate to lookup services and persist data: https://github.com/gerbrand/gwt-dynatablerf-spring

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for Spring integration, but RequestFactory expects:

- one session per request, aka "open session in view" (so the same Hibernate cache is used throughout the request)
- one transaction per service method

So your point about *“RequestFactory do things in different transactions, which is bad. I want the whole request to happen in the same transaction to take advantage of Hibernate cache”* is moot and wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction.
I'm surprised none of this is explained in the official documentation.

Comment: Yes, I know… If you feel inspired, feel free to send patches for the docs: http://gwtproject.org/makinggwtbetter.html (there are bugs open in the tracker too)